# How are the LEGO instruction manuals made?

Tags: instructions

I wish to know how the LEGO instruction manuals are made. What is the process currently used?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How are Lego sets designed](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/113/how-are-lego-sets-designed)

Comment: Is this specifically about making the _manuals_ (say, getting the breakdowns, printing, perhaps historically drafting), or about the whole conception-to-box product lifecycle? I read it as the former, which is not a duplicate.

Comment: I'm about to self answer myself. It may deserve it`s own question... you tell me. but the sets are built using Autodesk Maya.  The instructions are rendered. I should have some material to show... Let me check.

Comment: Not a duplicate - the people making the manuals are not even the designers.

Comment: Alright, agreed. Not a duplicate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### How lego does it today.

I found little information about Autodesk Maya being the 3D modeling software being used. Here`s a blurb about their current design process :

> Primary concept and development work takes place at the Billund
>   headquarters, where the company employs approximately 120 designers.
>   The company also has smaller design offices in the UK, Spain, Germany,
>   and Japan, which are tasked with developing products aimed
>   specifically at these markets.
>
> The average development period for a new product is around twelve
>   months, in three stages.
>
> The first stage is to identify market trends and developments,
>   including contact by the designers directly with the market; some are
>   stationed in toy shops close to holiday periods, while others
>   interview children.
>
> The second stage is the design and development of the product based
>   upon the results of the first stage. As of September 2008 the design
>   teams use 3D modeling software to generate CAD drawings from initial
>   design sketches.
>
> The designs are then prototyped using an in-house stereolithography
>   machine. These are presented to the entire project team for comment
>   and for testing by parents and children during the "validation"
>   process. Designs may then be altered in accordance with the results
>   from the focus groups.
>
> Virtual models of completed Lego products are built concurrently with
>   the writing of the user instructions. Completed CAD models are also
>   used in the wider organization, such as for marketing and packaging.

Source : [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego)

### How people do it themselves

LEGO provide software that does just that. Check for "[LEGO Digital Designer](http://designbyme.lego.com/en-us/Default.aspx?icmp=COCreateShareSpotlightUSDBM)" which allows to create a model, save a building manuals and buy the LEGO parts online.

Also check up this related question :["Do any programs exist that allow you to build own LEGO plans?"](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/12/do-any-programs-exist-that-allow-you-to-build-own-lego-plans)

For more information on how to create high quality computer images of LEGO models, check this question : "[How can I create synthetic imagery (rendering) of lego models?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/338/how-can-i-create-synthetic-imagery-rendering-of-lego-models)"

Comment: The http://designbyme.lego.com site doesn't work anymore,  but Lego Digital Designer can still be downloaded from https://www.lego.com/en-us/ldd